# Override default of ".{_format}" in routes using FOSRestBundle and Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosrestbundle

I am wondering if it is possible to define routes in FOSRestBundle methods that specify the format with something other than a "dot" preceding them.

For example, suppose I'd like the following to work:

```
 http://somesite.com/api/user/20        (renders in the default/fallback format)
 http://somesite.com/api/user/20/json   (renders in JSON)
 http://somesite.com/api/user/20/xml    (renders in XML)
```

If I attempt to define a route like:

```
/**
 * @Get("/user/{id}/{_format}
 */
public function getUserAction($id)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

I get this:

`Route pattern "/api/users/{maximum}/{_format}.{_format}" cannot reference variable name "_format" more than once.`

That made me realize that it -- and by it, I assume we are talking FOSRestBundle and not Symfony2 by default -- is automatically adding the ".{_format}" to the end of whatever route I define. I was surprised!

So right now, in my earlier example, it works as follows:

```
 http://somesite.com/api/user/20        (renders in the default/fallback format)
 http://somesite.com/api/user/20.json   (renders in JSON)
 http://somesite.com/api/user/20.xml    (renders in XML)
```

A small difference to be sure, but, I am trying to port over a legacy app that uses this syntax. Is what I am trying to do possible? If so, how can I disable that automatic addition of ".{_format}" to each route?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that this is currently not possible, see https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/333

Comment: Thanks for the link -- that at least shows me where to modify the bundle code to make it work. Perhaps it is time for me to commit a patch! :)

Comment: Johannes did it simply like that : https://github.com/schmittjoh/FOSRestBundle/commit/a2078202797e55b2372ad864a4695a25a3b94860

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over a year has passed and FOSRestBundle now supports the feature I was looking for above.

You can control this behavior via the following configuration:

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format:       ~
        include_format:       true
```

Set the `include_format` to `false` to remove the format from the route.

You can view the expanded configuration options for FOSRestBundle [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/configuration-reference.html).

Comment: Another way, which isn't linked to FOSRestBundle: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19412954/276648