# How to specify default format for FOS\RestBundle to json?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, fosrestbundle

My corresponding configuration is

```
fos_rest:
    view:
        view_response_listener: force

sensio_framework_extra:
    view:
        annotations: false
```

and it really annoys to specify the route as

```
@Route("/jobs", defaults={ "_format" = "json" })
```

every time.

So is it possible to specify it somewhere to be assumed by default?

PS:

If I remove `defaults={ "_format" = "json" }` and call the `/jobs` endpoint I'm getting an exception

```
Unable to find template "APIBundle:Jobs:post.html.twig".
```

PPS:

```
routing_loader:
    default_format: json
```

won't work because it's only used for automatic routes generation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The final answer is much easier and is irrelevant to FOS\RestBundle:

```
api:
    resource: "@APIBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    defaults: {_format: json} # <<<<<<<
    prefix:   /api/
```

Comment: @Mateo Tibaquirá: yes

Answer (score 11):

You may specify a `default_format` that the routing loader will use for the `_format` parameter if none is specified.

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
```

By default, routes are generated with {_format} string. If you want to get clean urls (`/jobs` instead `/jobs.{_format}`) then all you have to do is add some configuration:

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        include_format:       false
```

Have a look at the [FOSRestBundle documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md) for more informations.

Comment: It will **only** work if I use automatic route generation. With custom routes it doesn't work. Sorry, not an answer.

Comment: It works fine for me. With @Route('/foo') in my controller, calling /foo doesn't get any exception.

Comment: Is the format accepted as `json` eventually? If you remove that parameter - does the behaviour change?

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't test this solution myself but following [the documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.md#format-listener) it seems that you can use a default format by giving rules on path

<kbd>**config.yml**</kbd>

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        rules:
            # setting fallback_format to json means that instead of considering
            # the next rule in case of a priority mismatch, json will be used
            -
                path: '^/'
                host: 'api.%domain%'
                priorities: ['json', 'xml']
                fallback_format: json
                prefer_extension: false
```

With such, a request made with `Accept-headers` containing

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,application/json
```

Will result in a `json` Request format

Comment: I actually have seen it but didn't try yet. I will try tomorrow and will ping you with results. Thanks :-) But I already see a drawback - that way you **have** to pass `application/json` in the `Accept` header, while I want that `json` was just a format for every request unconditionally.

Comment: ... but after reading through that page thoroughly - I think that it might work. I'm sure it will. Anyway I will let you know tomorrow

Comment: Thanks for participation, I've found the real answer :-)